# tab-autocompletion problem in WSL(window sub linux)

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tab-completion

When using tab-completion in WSL(window sub linux), Some commands(cp, ls..) change prompt parameter

```sh
example)
define in bash_paths
  export WD=/mnt/c
```

When I input on prompt `cp $WD/` and then press tab, It changes `cp \$WD/`
but I want to change to `cp /mnt/c/` and to know why does it added `/`

thanks for reading

Answer (score 4):

See [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/318746/966107) by [user164395](https://askubuntu.com/users/164395/user164395).

Just enter the command `shopt -s direxpand` and you have the behaviour you want. If you don't want to do this every time, add it to the `.bashrc` file.

Also note that there are other answers to this question like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/54892/966107) from [kynan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22375/kynan). They suggest pressing `ESC` followed by `Contr`+`E` in order to expand the variable